# How to Make a Button Perform Single Click Instead of Double Click

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqt5

I'm experimenting on PyQt5. When I enter a value and click the push button to pass the value entered on my line edit, I noticed that it requires 2 mouse clicks for it to pass, and display the value on my plain text edit.

How will I change my codes to allow the entered value on the line edit to be passed by just 1 click?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 151, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 90, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 170, 181, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 170, 104, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 90, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Pass)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Pass the value entered here:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Accept and display the passed value:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PASS"))



    def Pass(self):

        accept = self.lineEdit.text()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.Get, accept))

    def Get(self, getA):

        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(getA)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    ui.Get(ui.Pass())

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: No the reason is that you only add the `Get` method the second time...

Comment: can you please explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.clicked` **fires the first time you click the button**. The problem is however that you register `Pass` to the button:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Pass)
```

Now `Pass` is defined as:

```
def Pass(self):
    accept = self.lineEdit.text()
    # connect a new event
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.Get, accept))
```

So the first time you click the button, you read the `accept`, and **only `connect` the `self.Get` method** to the button such that the **next time you hit the button**, `self.Get` will indeed be called.

In order to process the request straight away, you can simply modify the `Pass` method to:

```
def Pass(self):
    accept = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.Get(accept)
```

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a lot of confusion. I never knew it was that simple. Kudos to you!